# how to insert a picture into a table cell with text (SSRS 2008)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When insert a picture in a cell, text in cell is deleted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put a placeholder into the cell for the text and the picture. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting a rectangle into the cell and then adding whatever you need inside of the rectangle.